# jQuery 2.1.3 Ajax Access Denied error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have just updated to jQuery 2.1.3, and the Ajax calls are not working anymore. Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache:false,
    url: "xml/"+xmlName,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser,
    error: function(a, b, c) {
        alert(c); // this is where the errors happen, 'b' and 'c' are typically the only ones with values
    } // end error
});
```

The error is `Access Denied` on the `alert()`.

This works fine with jQuery 1.10.2 (no errors) but I need to update so we can work with Adobe Edge which uses a later version of jQuery. The build is not held on a server, just local testing at this stage so it cannot be a permission problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked out the request in the network tab for the Dev tools of your choice? Make certain you are still hitting the expected url, that all cookies you expect to pass are still being sent, and that you haven't inadvertently change something on your server. If you are getting `xmlName` from some element on the page make certain you are still getting it as expected (no unexpected spaces/characters etc)

Comment: To be clear, the error isn't "happening" on the alert line.  The alert is alerting the error message returned by the ajax call.  That is what `c` is here, the third parameter passed to the callback is the error thrown by the ajax call.

Comment: When you say it's "local testing", you are running a server locally right?  I don't believe ajax works if you just try to request a file off of your local file system (possibly browser-specific).

Comment: Seems to work fine in firefox, just IE11 is throwing an error with the ajax call, not using a server at all, seems to work in other versions of jQuery on IE, I will keep looking into it.

Comment: Found this bug, although it states it is happening across all versions of jQuery http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14475

Answer (score 0):

Since the bump from 1.10.x to 2.1.x has more than just ajax changes, you should be sure to check that other areas of the code that form the `xmlName` variable are still functioning as you expect them to. A major version bump like this can effect more than the single part of the code you're looking at.